# How can I fix the "segmentation fault" error in Visual Studio Code's terminal?

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-10, git-bash

On Windows 10, I have Visual Studio Code installed.

When I open the terminal (Git Bash) and type `less-watch-compiler`, I get the error:

> Segmentation fault

But if I go to the Git Bash terminal itself (outside Visual Studio Code) and type `less-watch-compiler`, the command works.

**How can I fix this problem?**

1. I reinstalled Git for Windows, but it didn't help.
2. I have the latest version of Visual Studio Code (1.36.1)
3. When I use the "cmd" editor within Visual Studio Code, it works fine as well.

Comment: This maybe? https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/74179

Comment: No, Mike, that link is about Ubuntu and as far as I can see, there is no answer there.

Comment: Ah, ok. Didn't look closely enough. Anyway, your probably want to ask there too as it might be a bug.

Answer (score 9):

Not sure if it's the same problem but I was also getting `segmentation fault` errors running VSCode with WSL.
What fixed it for me was:
`rm -rf ~/.vscode-server`
The next time I tried the command, VScode downloaded the necessary files and everything worked again.